# Django rest framework merging two serializers data based on following requirement

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have two models one is **Video** which contains all the user uploaded details and other model is **LikedVideo** which contains details of liked videos by the user.

**Video model**

```
class Video(models.Model):
    """
    All videos available for the users
    """
  
    video = models.FileField(blank=True, default='')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='user_videos', related_query_name='person', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(VideoCategory, related_name='video_category', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    channel = models.ForeignKey(Channel, related_name='video_channel', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    deleted_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=1)
    description = models.TextField(null=True)
    short_description = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.user.username}_{self.category.video_type}_{self.channel.channel_name}"
```

**LikedVideo model**

```
class LikedVideo(models.Model):
    """
    Contains all the liked videos by user
    """
    video = models.ForeignKey(Video, related_name='video_liked', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='user_liked', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    liked = models.BooleanField(default=0)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.user.username}"
```

**VideoSerializer**

```
class VideoSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    uploaded_at = serializers.ReadOnlyField()

    class Meta:
        model = Video
        fields = ["id", "video", "category", "uploaded_at", "channel", "description", "short_description"]

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        rep = super(VideoSerializer, self).to_representation(instance)
        rep['category'] = instance.category.video_type
        rep['channel'] = instance.channel.channel_name
        return rep

    def validate_channel(self, value):
        print(self.context['request'].user)
        if Channel.objects.filter(user=self.context['request'].user, channel_name=value).exists():
            return value
        raise serializers.ValidationError(_(f"Channel {value} does not belongs you. Please, enter a channel belongs to you"))
```

**LikedVideoSerializer**

```
class LikedVideoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = LikedVideo
        fields = ["id", "video", "liked", "user"]
```

**VideoListAPIView**

```
class VideoListAPIView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Video.objects.all()
    serializer_class = VideoSerializer

    def list(self, request, format=None):
        queryset = Video.objects.all()
        video_serializer = VideoSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        liked_videos = LikedVideo.objects.filter(user=request.user)
        liked_video_serializer = LikedVideoSerializer(liked_videos, many=True)

        print(video_serializer.data, "\n", liked_video_serializer.data)
```

**I need a serializer/s which contains all the Video Details and merge the liked video of the loggedin user to the Video details**

1. Need to build a Serializer which returns all the Video details.
2. In the video details need to add an extra field **video_liked** which is *True* or *False* for the logged in user. (liked video details should be for logged in user only and merge to total video details)

**for my logic I am getting the output as follows**

```
Video Details

[OrderedDict([('id', 8), ('video', '/media/dd_sNq8cWy.mp4'), ('category', 'Entertainment'), ('uploaded_at', datetime.datetime(2021, 5, 15, 8, 12, 52, 592654, tzinfo=<UTC>)), ('channel', 'lovelymouniii'), ('description', 'en'), ('short_description', 'msmms')]), OrderedDict([('id', 11), ('video', '/media/dd_9UP5kVD.mp4'), ('category', 'Entertainment'), ('uploaded_at', datetime.datetime(2021, 5, 16, 13, 17, 36, 328416, tzinfo=<UTC>)), ('channel', 'janaTrolling'), ('description', 'hhh'), ('short_description', 'hhh')]), OrderedDict([('id', 12), ('video', '/media/dd_wFe6tcb.mp4'), ('category', 'others'), ('uploaded_at', datetime.datetime(2021, 5, 16, 13, 38, 49, 917408, tzinfo=<UTC>)), ('channel', 'teluguGamer'), ('description', 'dsds'), ('short_description', 'dsdsdsd')]), OrderedDict([('id', 13), ('video', '/media/dd_JtxMzeD.mp4'), ('category', 'others'), ('uploaded_at', datetime.datetime(2021, 5, 16, 13, 50, 26, 645462, tzinfo=<UTC>)), ('channel', 'janaTrolling'), ('description', 'sdsd'), ('short_description', 'sdsds')])]
```

```
and liked videos as separate list
```

Display all the Videos and merge liked videos of the logged in user with the Video Details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way should be adding a property method to your Video model:

```py
@property
def is_liked(self):
    user = User.objects.get(id=request.user.id)
    liked = LikedVideo.objects.filter(video=self, user=user).values_list('liked')
    return liked
```

Then reference it directly in your VideoSerializer `fields`.

Comment: How to access request object in is_liked() ?

Comment: Thanks @NoneType Its working but slight change in Quering User Model change **user = User.objects.get(id=request.user.id)**  to  **user = User.objects.get(id=self.user.id)**